# LeetCode: count number of 1 bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to understand why below code won't work for this problem.

We are passing bits (0's & 1's) as an argument. If I do not use Bit operations and rather I first convert the integer to charArray and iterate over it to count the no of '1' and then return it, why it does not work?

```
 public class Solution {
        // you need to treat n as an unsigned value
        public int hammingWeight(int n) {
             int count=0;
            for(char c:String.valueOf(n).toCharArray())
            {
                if('1'==c)
                    ++count;
            }
            
            return count;
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"why it does not work?"* --- Example: Input is `42`, which is `101010` in binary, so it has *three* 1-bits, however `String.valueOf(n)` returns `"42"`, which has *zero* characters equal to `'1'`.

Comment: Easiest solution is calling [`Integer.bitCount(n)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount-int-): *"Returns the number of one-bits"*

Answer (score 1):

You are counting `1` in a decimal string, you can eaily convert it to a binary string by `Integer.toBinaryString()`

```
public int hammingWeight(int n) {
    int count=0;
    for(char c:Integer.toBinaryString(n).toCharArray())
    {
        if('1'==c)
            ++count;
    }

    return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this is Java, I am surprised nobody mentioned the JDK method `Integer.bitCount(i)` of `java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score -1):

We don't have to convert the n to string, this would pass just fine:

```
class Solution {
    public static int hammingWeight(int n) {
        int ones = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            ones = ones + (n & 1);
            n = n>>>1;
        }
        return ones;
    }
}
```

Comment: Question says *"if I do not use Bit operations"*, so answering with a solution using bit-operations is not useful.